# Guile | How to parse a file?

Tags: gnu, guile

I am trying to figure out how to manipulate variables of a guile script through a config file, instead of having to edit the source code.

Got a file called *test.cfg* that contains this:

```
name = Gareth
my-num = 123
rand-string = Hello, world!
```

Here is a script named *read-file* that I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/guile \
-e main -s
!#

(use-modules (ice-9 textual-ports))

(define (read-file file)
  (call-with-input-file file
    (lambda (port)
      (get-string-all port))))

(define get-name
  (call-with-input-file "test.cfg"
    ;; Code to get value of `name` from test.cfg here.
    ))

(define (main args)
  (display (read-file "test.cfg"))
  (display (get-name))
  (newline))
```

In the end result, when `name` is changed in *test.cfg*, `get-name` in *read-file* should return the new value.

Comment: Using Scheme syntax in the config file will be much easier.